# Can Tolkien's work be considered as pre-raphaelic art?

Tags: terminology

A fellow friend of mine is really interested in Preraphaelites. Is the classification only subject to historic line-up?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Maybe you could explain what similarities you see between Tolkien's work and the pre-Raphaelites' works.

Comment: You've provided a relevant source in a [comment](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/24994/can-tolkiens-work-be-considered-as-pre-raphaelic-art#comment37695_24997) to an answer; could you please [edit] the question to show all the prior research you've done on this topic? This should provide clarity as to what context you're working from and thus help answerers.

Answer (score 1):

I have never heard the term used outside of the fine arts (painting, sculpture).  Additionally, I do think it is a time/historical concept - although I guess you could call a recent painting that imitates medieval art pre-Raphaelite like art.

Tolkien would not be pre-Raphaelite in either context.

Comment: It is used in the context of poetry as well: https://www.bl.uk/romantics-and-victorians/articles/the-pre-raphaelites